# Did Carlsen really defeat Kasparov?

Tags: strategy

I saw on youtube little Carlsen played against Kasparov, and I see that Kasparov really focused to the game, but finally Carlsen (draw) won the game. How a little kid like that can win against the great Kasparov ?. I almost believe that game has been "arranged", has Carlsen ever won played against kasparov ? (seriously)

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant the article: [Boy meets Beast in Reykjavik](http://en.chessbase.com/post/boy-meets-beast-in-reykjavik). No, Carlsen didn't win the match - he lost the match by 0.5-1.5. Read the article for the game. It is important to note while Carlsen had a better position, it was not absolutely winning, especially in a rapid game (it was a rapid match).

Carlsen has never beaten Kasparov in the database, in fact, they have never played a standard game. This is not surprising, Carlsen raised in ranks when Kasparov was finishing his career. However, it's almost certain that Carlsen has beaten Kasparov at least in blitz while they were training. We don't have the games so we don't know who was a better blitz player.